# How to inject activity scope object into Application Scope Object?

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2, dagger

I'm making an android app and following mvvm architecture through dagger 2. the problem is regarding scoping where Camera preview from activity module want to inject it into AppManager of Application interface DataManager scope. getting error image.crystalapps.mytrackercamerax.ui.cameraactivity.CameraPreview cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
how can i use CameraPreview from activity scope into Datamanager interface....

//AppComponent

```
 @ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class  , ViewModelProviderFactoryModule.class , AppModule.class , ActivitiesBuilderModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {

   void inject(BaseApplication appComponent);


    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{

        @BindsInstance
        Builder appComponent(Application application);
        AppComponent build();

    }

}
```

// Application Level Module

```
  @Module(includes = ActivitiesBuilderModule.class)
   public class AppModule {


@ApplicationScope
@Provides
DataManager provideDataManager(AppDataManager appDataManager){
    return appDataManager;

}
```

}

// ActivityBuilder

```
@Module
 public abstract class ActivitiesBuilderModule {

@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {CameraViewModelModule.class  ,CameraContentModule.class})
abstract CameraActivity getCameraActivity();
```

}

// Activity Module Dependenices

```
  @Module
  public class CameraContentModule {





 @Provides
  CameraPreview provideCamraPrevierw(Application application){
 return new CameraPreview(application);}}
```

// here i want to pass camerapreview from activity scope into application scope

```
 public class AppDataManager implements DataManager{

 public static final String TAG="Mytag";

  private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

@Inject
public AppDataManager(CameraPreview cameraPreview ){
    this.cameraPreview=cameraPreview;


    Log.i(TAG, "AppDataManager: "+cameraPreview);

}
```

}

//BaseViewModel where i'm using applicationScope DataManager

```
  public class BaseViewModel extends ViewModel {

private DataManager appDataManager;

@Inject
public BaseViewModel(DataManager appDataManager){
    this.appDataManager=appDataManager;
}
```

}

// Application Class

```
 public class BaseApplication extends DaggerApplication  {







@Override
protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appComponent(this).build()
            ;
}
```

}

Comment: Pass it in a method

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can't pass it because i need a reference of it in AppDataManager..

Comment: Exactly, so pass it to the AppDataManager

Comment: thanks for replying but my question is can i pass Activityscope class reference (CameraPreview) into Application Scope (DataManager) which is the interface of AppDataManager.